# Financial tracker with simple but uncommon features

Tags: ios, iphone-app, finance

For the last week, I've been trying to find an iOS financial app that satisfies my needs, but have come completely empty.

I have very few requirements for a financial tracker app (basically, they can be fulfilled by a moderately advanced Excel spreadsheet, but that's not exactly a mobile-friendly interface):

1. Obviously, the ability to input expense and income transactions. Nothing more complicated than an amount, category, and description. [*99% of apps have this*]
2. An ability to create multiple accounts (cash, bank #1, bank #2, liabilities, receivables, etc…). A quasi-double-entry bookkeeping, so to say. And, by extension, the ability to create a transfer transaction between different accounts. [*85% of apps have this*]
3. An ability to have separate currencies inside one account. Here start the problems with a suitable app. Most of them offer automatic currency conversion to the default one (requires a lot of arithmetic and editing transactions after the fact), and/or suggest creating different accounts for each currency (really tedious when traveling into a new country, my account list would swell to a double-digit number). [*So, at this point something like 15% of apps fulfill my use case*]
4. An ability to divide transactions into multiple sheets/projects/whatever it is called in a particular app. Almost every app provides statistics for a calendar month, some of them give an option to set a starting day of a fiscal month, but these are too strict for me. I like to keep my fiscal months start- and end-points flexible; and also to separate my day-to-day expenses from special projects, business trips, vacations and so on. [*Here I run into a wall. I haven't been able to find an app with exactly this functionality*]
5. Import from (and preferably export to) csv/xlsx/sqlite. I have several years worth of transaction history entered already, but the current app was last updated approximately the time I installed it, and is going to break when I install the newest iOS.

I don't need any fancy features like recurring expenses, budgeting, bank statement reconciliation, breath-taking 3D charts… I just need the 5 functions I've mentioned, and the ability to filter transactions and show their statistics along these lines of category/account/sheet.

This has proved to be a surprisingly difficult search, and if nobody knows some app I've missed, I'm seriously considering just writing yet another, 101st income tracker app just to fit my needs…